# Insufficient privileges error with sonarRunner

Tags: jenkins, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

I am getting Insufficient privileges error running sonar. This started happening after I upgraded sonarQube to 5.0.

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
>   ERROR: Caused by: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@152f931e[key=........]'
>   ERROR: Caused by: {"errors":[{"msg":"Insufficient privileges"}]}

For the existing projects, I renamed the key and now I have new sonar projects. Those seems to be working fine for now. The new projects that are created are throwing this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue appears to be a bug in the Sonar Server 5.0 release.

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6091

In order to work around it the 'SEE SOURCE CODE' project permissions can be set to include 'Anyone' from the admin page as in the below screen shot:

[image]

Obviously, this is not ideal in an unprotected environment because the source code can be viewed by anyone with access to the Sonar server API, but hopefully its addressed in the 5.1 release of Sonar Server.

Comment: Sadly, the link has gone dead with the Codehaus deco... Is [this the right one?](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6091)

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me (Sonar 6.1) was caused by the creation of the project in SonarQube: at the first execussion of the scanner, it creates the corresponding project in SonarQube, what I didn't allow for all users...

Restore the right for creating projects allow the scanner to successfully work.