# Sonarqube “Insufficient privileges” - Encoding issue suspected

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

After an upgrade of Sonar from the version 4.5 to the version 5.1.1, a lot of jobs are failing now. But some projects are succesfully analysed .

The issue seems to be the same of these posts : [SonarQube "Insufficient privileges"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534221/sonarqube-insufficient-privileges) & [Insufficient privileges error with sonarRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391746/insufficient-privileges-error-with-sonarrunner)

**but** this is not a credential bug because some of my projects are successfully analysed.

I have this message on Jenkins side (Sonar runner log) when the problem occurs:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:26.443s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 07 10:35:46 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 54M/765M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXX: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@23e88d14[key=src/main/webapp/js/XXXXXXX/XXXXjs,path=src/main/webapp/js/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX.js,filename=XXXXX.js,language=JavaScript]': Insufficient privileges -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project Opale: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@23e88d14[key=src/main/webapp/js/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX.js,path=src/main/webapp/js/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX.js,filename=XXXX.js,language=JavaScript]'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@23e88d14[key=src/main/webapp/js/etiquetage/compositionTsf/DetailCompositionTsfController.js,path=src/main/webapp/js/etiquetage/compositionTsf/DetailCompositionTsfController.js,filename=DetailCompositionTsfController.js,language=JavaScript]'
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@23e88d14[key=src/main/webapp/js/etiquetage/compositionTsf/DetailCompositionTsfController.js,path=src/main/webapp/js/etiquetage/compositionTsf/DetailCompositionTsfController.js,filename=DetailCompositionTsfController.js,language=JavaScript]'
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:104)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.execute(DecoratorsExecutor.java:71)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient privileges
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.handleHttpException(ServerClient.java:137)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:107)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:99)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:87)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.DefaultServerLineHashesLoader.loadHashesFromWs(DefaultServerLineHashesLoader.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.DefaultServerLineHashesLoader.getLineHashes(DefaultServerLineHashesLoader.java:38)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.SourceHashHolder.initHashes(SourceHashHolder.java:52)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.SourceHashHolder.getHashedSource(SourceHashHolder.java:65)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTracking.setChecksumOnNewIssues(IssueTracking.java:66)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTracking.track(IssueTracking.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator.doDecorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:139)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator.decorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:113)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:96)
    ... 57 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' marked build as failure
```

And when I check the SonarQube's access log and I found that :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2015:03:38:14 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/sources/hash?key=XXX.YYY%3AZZZZZ%3Asrc%2Fmain%2Fwebapp%2Fjs%2FXXXX%2FXXXX%2FXXXXXX.js HTTP/1.0" 403 46 "-" "SonarQube Maven/3.0.5"
```

We see that server returns a 403 error. Then it's normal that sonarrunner print an authentification issue in its log.

However, When I compare source code with my project which build successfully, I observe they contains UTF-8 source with no accented characters.

Then I've add an accented char into a source file and the analysis has failed.

I suspect a problem with the hash method on source files which contains accented symbols.

Comment: You didn't include any log from sonar.log (logs on server side). Didn't you find anything relevant there? You could increase log level and add it to your post.

Comment: I doubt the encoding of source files content matter here. The file name (which appears in the URL), however, might be. Do yo see a pattern there?

Comment: "You didn't include any log from sonar.log (logs on server side). Didn't you find anything relevant there? You could increase log level and add it to your post." --> No there's nothing into this log file.



"I doubt the encoding of source files content matter here. The file name (which appears in the URL), however, might be. Do yo see a pattern there?" --> Warning: the encoding is always the same for all my projects : UTF-8. I suspect the hash method to fail when there is at least one accented symbol into a source file which must be decorated.

Answer (score 0):

A 403 error is an authorization error.

This WS returns hashes of the lines of the requested file and you need source code permission on the file to get a response (ie. source code permission on the project the file belongs to). Content of the file has nothing to do with authorization.

If you get a 403, you just don't have the right permissions on the project the file belongs to. Check you configuration.

Only scenario I can imagine where encoding could be involved in this case, is the following:

- you have accentuated characters in the key (so, either in the module key or the file path and file name)
- incorrectly encoded or decoded, this key matches the key of another file and project than the one you would expect and you don't have the right permissions on it
- this implies you have modules which name are nearly the same
- I hardly see how you may end up in such situation in the first place

Comment: There is no accentuad characted in the key. I check the permission and the sonar user has all right : same result. I've retry this test : I've take a project that have been successfully analyzed, I've changed a source file to add a "é" character, and now the analyse has failed (same error). I've changed the source file to remove the "é" character and now the analyse is ok.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with sonarrunner? Because there is no log in the access on the "/sonar/api/sources/hash?key=" endpoint for sucessully analysed project.

Comment: a server-side issue is indeed quite unlickly. To get help with a problem on the sonnar-runner side, I suggest you edit your question and provide the version of sonar-runner, a sample reproducer source file, the list & version of plugins installed on your SQ instance, together with the sonar-runner logs in successful and failing cases. Not my area of expertise, someone else might help you